# Building Android app from the command line with Gradle on Windows: Version too old

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

*Foreword: I know that there are dozens of questions about the error I'm getting but still I don't think my question is a duplicate because it seems all older questions refer to building using Android Studio whereas I'm trying to build an Android app from the command line on Windows.*

So here we go: I've just installed the latest Android Studio, Android NDK and JDK 8 on a Windows 7 system. I've created a minimal test project with a `build.gradle` which looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I open a command line and type `gradle wrapper` I get the following error:

```
Build file 'D:\TestProject\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 3.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\TestProject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.085 secs
```

I cannot follow the advice presented in the error message because the file `D:\TestProject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` simply doesn't exist yet. AFAIU, this stuff is part of the wrapper and should be generated by a call to `gradle wrapper` so prompting me to modify a file which doesn't exist doesn't make too much sense to me.

What is even more confusing is the fact that when I open the `HelloJNI` test project provided by Google in Android Studio and go to `File/Project Structure/Project` the Gradle version is shown as 3.3. However, looking inside `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle` shows that I only have 3.2 installed, not 3.3, because there is only a `gradle-3.2` directory inside `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle`.

So this is all rather confusing and I'm out of ideas about how to fix this. That's why any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I open a command line and type gradle wrapper I get the following error

The fact that this actually runs means that you installed a standalone local copy of Gradle. You are not running the Gradle Wrapper yet, as that would be `./gradlew`, not `gradle`.

So, visit [the Gradle installation site](https://gradle.org/install) and upgrade your standalone local copy of Gradle to 3.3.

Comment: No, I don't have a standalone local copy of Gradle installed. I've just added `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin` to my path environment variable. Could the problem be related to that?

Comment: @Andreas: Well, I would describe that as an unusual approach, and one that I would not recommend, as you do not know the circumstances under which Android Studio might eventually remove that directory. I recommend that you either use Android Studio to create your project (via the new-project wizard) or use a standalone copy of Gradle to set up your wrapper.

Comment: Ok, I've now installed the latest Gradle version independently from Android Studio and now it's working. But I'm still wondering why it didn't work from the command line with the Gradle that came with Android Studio. When using Android Studio Gradle worked fine, when using the command line it said it needed at least Gradle 3.3. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

In your top `build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = "3.5"
}
```

Then run the command:

```
gradlew wrapper
```

After this is done, you should be able to re-sync with the IDE.